# Qt pass focus between windows

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

In the following example I have a Qt button which opens a pop-out window. However, the pop-out window takes the focus entirely. Is it possible to modify this such that I can still interact with the main window by moving the mouse over it, e.g. to change the value of QDoubleSpinBox even when the pop-out window is open? I think I may need to use the QtHoverEvent class put I can't find a good example of how to do this.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QDoubleSpinBox,\
    QLabel



class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        btn = QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn.move(50, 50) 
        btn2 = QDoubleSpinBox(self)
        btn2.move(50,100)

        self.sideWindowTest = sideWindowTest(self)
        btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.sideWindowTest.setupWindow())

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main')

        self.show()

class sideWindowTest(object):

    myWdg = None

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.viewer = parent

    def initiateMenuBar(self):
        self.myWdg.setWindowTitle('Phasing')
        self.myWdg.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
        MenuBar = QVBoxLayout()
        self.labels = {
            'phase 0': QLabel('Phase 0', self.myWdg),
        }
        self.inputs = {
            'phase 0': QDoubleSpinBox(self.myWdg),
        }

        for i in self.inputs.values():
            i.installEventFilter(self.myWdg)

        self.inputs['phase 0'].setValue(0)

        MenuBar.addWidget(self.labels['phase 0'])
        MenuBar.addWidget(self.inputs['phase 0'])
        MenuBar.addStretch(1)

        return MenuBar

    def setupWindow(self):

        if not self.myWdg:
            self.myWdg = QWidget()

            MenuBar = self.initiateMenuBar()

            grid = QGridLayout()
            grid.setSpacing(10)        

            grid.addLayout(MenuBar, 0, 0, 1, 2)
            self.myWdg.setLayout(grid)
            self.myWdg.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 100)

        self.myWdg.show()
        self.myWdg.activateWindow() 


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but you have to explicitly wrap your `QWidget`'s in a `QDialog` or a `QMainWindow`.  By default, if you create a orphan `QWidget` (as you are doing), Qt will wrap it in a `QDialog`.

Just change your class type to `QDialog`.  Also, you should probably pass in the initial main window as the parent.

```
btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.sideWindowTest.setupWindow(self))

...


def setupWindow(self, parent=None):

    if not self.myWdg:
        self.myWdg = QDialog(parent)
```

Comment: I have tried this suggestion but it doesn't solve the problem. After changing to QDialog and making the other suggestions above, clicking the button opens the second window which still takes the focus entirely from the main window.